# UIAccessibilityPostNotification for TTS - allowed in app?

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility, uiaccessibility-notification

It appears that one could use  UIAccessibilityPostNotification for TTS thus:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, @"the sky is now blue");
```

However, this raises two questions:

1) Is this allowed by app store rules? Seems mighty close to using a private API...

2) My uses want TSS, not VoiceOver in general. Is there a way to temporarily enable VO, do the TTS call, then disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answers are:

1) Yes

2) No

Several people have asked about 2, but nobody has come up with a way to do it. I suppose that makes a lot of sense really.

I ended up using the iSpeech voices for my project instead. Cloud based, but free.